# Return nested array laravel event

Tags: laravel

I'm, trying to return a nested array through an Event. But I'm not pretty sure how this would work:

This is what I got in my controller:

```
public function send(Request $request, Group $group){

        $message = new Message([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'group_id' => $request->groupId,
            'message' => $request->message
        ]);
        $message->save();

        event(new MessageSent($message));

        return response()->json([
        "code" => 200,
        "message" => "Message successfully sent"
        ]);
        
    }
```

this is what I got in my event:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Http\Resources\Group as GroupResource;
use App\Http\Resources\Message as MessageResource;

use App\Message;
use App\User;

class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;


    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $arr = $message->toArray();
        $user = User::where('id', $this->message->user_id)->first();
        $arr['user'] = $user->toArray();

        return $arr;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('group.' . $this->message->group->id);
    }

}
```

When the event is triggered, I'm only getting the Message model,but not the `return $arr;`

my goal is to return the array the following way, this is an edit to ask if the provided solution won't affect this structure as the solution makes the array to provide object inside object, but there might be a difference:

```
{
  "data": {
    "_id": 1, // ID of the message
    "text": "test", // content of the message
    "createdAt": "timestamp", 
    "user": [ // data of the user
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "User name",
        "email": "User email",
        "created_at": "timestamp",
        "updated_at": "timestamp"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: the data key, is necessary?

Comment: Well, key will be defined in the front-end, don't worry about that. That one is easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare you var in the MessageSent class, try this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Http\Resources\Group as GroupResource;
use App\Http\Resources\Message as MessageResource;

use App\Message;
use App\User;

class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    public $data;


    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $user = User::where('id', $this->message->user_id)->first();
        $this->message->user = $user;
        $this->data= $message->toArray();

    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('group.' . $this->message->group->id);
    }

}
```

In this way, you can retrieve the array data

Comment: This seems to be the answer, I updated the post, please check the addition. It is doing what I need, but it's returning the user as an object: `"user": Object {` will this affect?

Comment: you should map your model, and get this result

Comment: So, not it's just a matter of formatting everything I need in the front-end, right? :)

Comment: Or, I can define `_id` inside the `user` array? But that seems a bit complicated, isn't it?

Comment: attempt it in that way

Comment: The variable user is not defined, haha

Comment: Sorry, fixed, try now

Comment: Wow, seems now to be a bit unorganized, haha

Comment: https://gist.github.com/danslabs/3dfe1743867bedf624641c3340267a43

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216935/discussion-between-jonnathan-carrasco-and-daniel-logvin).